# How can I make these inner surfaces smooth?

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to get rid of those lines while still keeping that solid feel to the object. I want the object to be sharp, so smoothing would make it look like plastic.

[image]

Any help for removing those lines while still keeping the solid feel?

Thanks.

Comment: You mean smooth shading does not result in the desired effect?

Comment: @Dimali using smooth shading makes everything smooth. I don't want that. I want this object to look sharp, but those lines kinda ruin the close up shots.

Comment: Check the Auto Smooth box in **Properties>>Object Data>>Normals** panel.  Then enable Smooth-Shading.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/89570/simple-question-how-to-smoothout-faces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to get rid of these lines inbetween the cutout is to select the affected faces and set them to smooth shading.
You then can select the edges, press CTRL+E and mark them as sharp.

Add an Edge Split modifier and make sure that the Sharp Edges checkbox is active.

Alternatively you can also select all the faces of the model, set the shading to smooth and then add the Edge Split modifier and control the Split Angle.

This should give you the desired effect.

[image: smooth shading for faces, mark sharp for edges]

Comment: Thanks, just what I needed. I appreciate the visual explanation.