# Simple question, how to smoothout faces?

Tags: modeling, rendering, blender-internal-render-engine

I'm a veteran of 3dsmax who hasn't modeled anything in half a decade trying to get my head around Blender.  So simple reproduction of what I am seeing, I create a cylidner, I add autosmooth, I then add Edge Split modifier but my render still has flat shaded faces.  I am surely missing something?

Thanks!

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/55975/what-is-the-role-of-auto-smooth

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make an object smooth, you either go to the left panel>Tools>Edit>Smooth or press space and type "shade smooth".

Then if you want to make the top faces flat shaded, use auto smooth or Edge slplit modifier, but they are essentially the same so one should only use one of them not both.

Comment: Thank you, everything I found through search was past that particular step!